# Line Break in VB scripting is not working when multiple rows combined into a cell

Tags: excel, vbscript, line-breaks

I am trying to concatenate values of an array(data2) values to an variable (oldValue) and pasting that in a cell of an workbook.
I used chr(13) as line break while doing concatenation.It is perfectly working when am trying to display the concatenated Value(OldValue) in Message Box.
But when am trying to assign to a cell value, the Line breaks is not working. Is there any option to make the Line breaks work inside the cell?

```
For i = 2 to iMax
        fc=data1(i,4)
        Dim oldValue
        oldValue="" 
        For k = 1 to fc
            oldValue = oldValue & chr(13) & data2(i,k,1)&"-"&data2(i,k,2)&chr(13)
            'objExcel1.Cells(i,j).Value = oldValue & chr(13) & data2(i,k,1)&"-"&data2(i,k,2)&chr(13)
        Next            
        For j = 1 to 6
        If (j=5) then               
            Msgbox(oldValue)
            objExcel1.Cells(i,j).Value = oldValue           
        else
            objExcel1.Cells(i,j).Value = data1(i,j) 
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Perfect!!!.It worked .. Thanks BruceWayne:)

Answer (score 2):

To force a return in the cell, switch `CHR(13)` with `vbCrLf`.